# Retrieving next 2 lines of text after pattern match using grep

Tags: grep, full-text-search

I am using the following command to search for text using grep:

```
grep --include=*.{php,py} -rnw 'DIR' -F -e 'TEXT'
```

Considering the following text:

```
This is so funny
This is pyramid
Hello World
How are you
```

How can I modify the above grep command (or if there is some alternative) to fetch the next two line if I specify 'funny' as match expression?

```
grep --include=*.{php,py} -rnw 'DIR' -F -e 'funny'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -A <number>` to get that number of lines following a match.